# Jesus' completed messianic prophecies

Tags: life-of-jesus, prophecy

When we look for the messianic prophecies that Jesus completed, should we only look at the Old Testament?  What would be the basis for using the prophecies which were in books written after his death?

Comment: There are not many of these, but Jesus is reported to have made them about Himself prior to His death.  For example, the parable of the vineyard owner was a parable about His death.  Obviously, He fulfilled that.  To be sure, the prophecies in the Old Testament bear more weight to us today.  Yet, those who heard those prophecies and then saw Him fulfill them probably gave significant weight to them as well.

Comment: What are the prophecies in the Old Testament?

Comment: which New Testament prophecies are you talking about so I can look them up...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually when people use the term "Messianic Prophecy," they're referring to a prophecy concerning the "Annointed One" (messiah) that was to come. (Here's a [list of 45+](https://bible.org/article/messianic-prophecies).) These prophetic predictions/descriptions were about some yet unknown person to come.

When Jesus speaks of himself, it could certainly be described as prophecy, it doesn't exactly fit the pattern of previous "messianic prophecies."

The OT Messianic prophecies are another assertion of the validity of Jesus, because these predictions were made and recorded hundreds of years before Jesus was born.

Jesus' predictions about himself don't provide the same kind of external proof because to assume they were accurate presumes that the author is recording the truth, and that presumption is essentially assuming the conclusion that Jesus is the Messiah. A pessimistic analysis of these predictions might say that they were fabricated *after* Jesus came and so, of course they are accurate. Whereas the Hebrews had spent the previous 400+ years studying the predictions made before Jesus' fulfillment of any of them. The accuracy of those predictions serves as proof that Jesus' coming bears the stamp of God.

Answer (score 1):

In the Old Testament the prophecies about messiah are written before the events took place. But in New Testament you have to be careful because if it speaks of something that already happened it's not a prophecy unless written on something else before the events took place, like the Old Testament. If it's not found anywhere else from before the events happened, then by definition it is not a prophecy.

So to look for Messianic prophecies that have been completed since then, you have to go to the Old Testament. To look for Messianic prophecies that happened after it was written, or yet to happen you could look in the New Testament.